# Count multiple values in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table and would like to count the appearance of the values (no sum)

```
ID  status
============
1   2
2   3
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   2
```

and I need following result:

```
status_1 status_2 status_3 status_4
===================================
3        2        1        0
```

Can I do this with a single SQL statement?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level (if you have one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
sum(if(status=1,1,0)) as status_1,
sum(if(status=2,1,0)) as status_2,
sum(if(status=3,1,0)) as status_3,
sum(if(status=4,1,0)) as status_4
from foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a group query, with a count function:

```
select status, count(status)
from tablename
group by status
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
   sum(case status When 1 Then 1 End) status1,
   sum(case status When 2 Then 1 End) status2,
   sum(case status When 3 Then 1 End) status3,
   sum(case status When 4 Then 1 End) status4,
   etc.
From table
```

Comment: This should have `else 0` to match the output in the question.

Comment: Charles - I prefer `CASE` over `IF` because it's more "standard", but your answer will show `NULL` for `status4`, whereas the OP wants it to be zero.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(status) where status = x
```

Would yield the count for a single status.

Perhaps you could nest this statement but that may be inefficient.

Edit:
Group By is the way to go. See other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is important to notice that what you are asking would imply a code modification as the supported status change. I think it could be better to have the result in several lines.
This one could give you the same resuts in several rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT status) FROM mytable;
```

So you can iterate over the hole time, without query modifications. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this one will help you

```
select status, count(*) from tablename
group by status
```